# Change object's string representation in template

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I my template, I have this call:

```
{{ conversation.get_product() }}
```

That prints this:

```
<Product u'Box soft '>
```

I want it to print this:

```
Box soft
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control what is returned by the `get_product` call, you'll need to overwrite the class's `__repr__` or `__str__` methods.

If you don't control that class, i.e. if it's part of a separate package, then you'll need to investigate that `Product` object and instead of calling

```
{{ conversation.get_product() }}
```

you'll need to call the appropriate method to get the data that you want from the object, i.e.:

```
{{ conversation.get_product().name }}
```